# Show that if $X$ is uncountable and $(X,F)$ is the co-countable topology on $X$, is not compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Show that if $X$ is uncountable, and $F$ is the collection of sets $E$ such that $X\setminus E$ is empty or at most countable. Then $(X,F)$ the co-countable topology on $X$, is not compact.

I know I've got to make a collection of sets in $F$ which don't have a finite sub cover. I want to say I can get a collection $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n=X$ such that each $V_{1}^c\supset V_{2}^c\supset ...$ are countable. Since if I then take only a finite collection of these, I'd have $(\bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i)^c$ isn't empty, as one of them has the smallest complement, which is non empty. So they don't cover $X$. But I'm not sure how to make such a set.

Maybe I can just take any countable subset of $X$, call it $U$ and define $V_1$ as $X\setminus U$, then define $V_2$ as $X\setminus (U\setminus \{u\})$ for some $u\in U$, and continue this by saying $V_i=X\setminus(V_{i-1}\setminus \{u\})$ for some $u\in U$. Which I believe will cover $X$ eventually because any $x\in X$ is either in $V_1$ at the start or is in $V_i=X\setminus (V_{i-1}\setminus \{x\})$ but I can't cover $X$ with only finitely many since I'll always miss some subset of $U$.

I'm not sure if I can actually construct such a set though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea will work if you execute it carefully. You need to start with a countably infinite set $U=\{u_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. (*Countable* normally means *finite or countably infinite*, and you need to exclude the finite case.) Now define your sets $V_n$ recursively: $V_1=X\setminus U$, and $V_{n+1}=V_n\cup\{u_n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

> Note that $V_{n+1}$ isn’t $X\setminus(V_n\setminus\{u_n\})$, as you tried to define it: we need to remover $u_n$ from the **complement** of $V_n$, not from the open set $V_n$ itself. If we set $U_n=X\setminus V_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, $U_1=U$, and $U_{n+1}=U_n\setminus\{u_n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. We’re removing one point at a time from the countable complements and thereby adding it to the open sets themselves.

Now let $x\in X$. If $x\notin U$, then $x\in V_1$. If $x\in U$, then $x=u_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so $x\in V_{n+1}$. Thus, $\mathscr{V}=\{V_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is an open cover of $X$. If $\mathscr{V}_0$ is any finite subset of $\mathscr{V}$, there is a largest $n$ such that $V_n\in\mathscr{V}_0$, and it’s easy to see that $\bigcup\mathscr{V}_0=V_n$. The construction ensures that $u_n\notin V_n$, so $\mathscr{V}_0$ does not cover $X$, and $\mathscr{V}$ is an open cover of $X$ with no finite subcover.